# How is use onbefore unload event in angular

Tags: angular

I have two routes Employees List and Home screen.In employees list route i have a component which is used to add new employee.I will be showing that component in a dialog.Without saving the changes if user clicks on browser back button i need to take confirmation from the user.
I tried to use `onbeforeunload` event

```
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    public doSomething($event) {
      console.log('do I see this?');
      return false;
    }
```

But the problem is the event is not called when i open the dialog and click on browser back button.It is only called when i reload the page then it shows confirmation.
What i want to achieve is i want to show i confirmation dialog to user when user clicks on browser back button.Can somebody please tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Is the dialog a separate component?

Comment: Yes... I am using Material dialog to show the component

Answer (score 4):

Try like this following in your component.ts file :

```
import { Component, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    return false;
}
```